# PostgreSQL - querying records between the values of two different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was forced into a non-normalized situation. I have a reports, drivers, alerts, and alert_codes table. All have relationships. But when a report is created with the driver_id field populated with the driver id, all subsequent reports should be associated with the driver as well (even though those reports' driver_id column WILL NOT be populated) until a report is created whose alert whose alert code has a name field equal to "Inside fence". Ideally it would be nice that each report's driver_id field is populated but that's not the situation I am in.

*So I tried to build the most effective query possible, but I am stuck on the part of the query that grabs reports between the date specified and the reports whose alert codes has a string of "Inside fence" within the given month.*

This is what I came up with but is giving an "operator does not exist: boolean <= character varying" error:

```
SELECT reports.* FROM reports 
INNER JOIN alerts ON alerts.report_id = reports.id 
INNER JOIN alert_codes ON alert_codes.id = alerts.code 
WHERE (reports.unit_id = 3000 AND extract(MONTH FROM reports.time) = 3 
AND extract(YEAR FROM reports.time) = 2013) 
BETWEEN reports.time = '2013-03-20 15:21:05.379941' 
AND alert_codes.name = 'Inside fence'
ORDER BY reports.time asc
```

Something tells me that I can't use two different columns with that BETWEEN clause. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT reports.* FROM reports
WHERE 
reports.time >= '2013-03-20 15:21:05.379941' 
AND reports.time <= (
    SELECT min(r2.time) from reports r2 
    INNER JOIN alerts ON alerts.report_id = r2.id 
    INNER JOIN alert_codes ON alert_codes.id = alerts.code 
    WHERE r2.time >= '2013-03-20 15:21:05.379941' 
    AND alert_codes.name = 'Inside fence')
```

I excluded the `unit_id = 3000` clause. You can place it where it makes sense (either in the outer `WHERE` or the inner `WHERE`).

Comment: The problem with the query is that its only going to select where the alert_codes.name is equal to 'Inside fence'. I need to select ALL records starting from date '2013-03-20 15:21:05.379941' to where there is a record whose alert code has a name of 'Inside fence'.

Comment: Im trying to avoid any programmatic iteration (e.g. ruby, python) to reduce server response time.

Comment: Beautiful query and it worked very fast! I need to remember about those nested select statements. It worked a lot faster than doing it programmatically.